# Why could Steve Rogers move Mjolnir but not lift it?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, mjolnir

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* when the Avengers are all taking turns trying to lift Mjolnir from the coffee table, Steve Rogers is shown moving it about half an inch or so but not actually lifting it. Presumably whatever enchantment there is on Mjolnir that determines "worthiness"( "whosever wields this hammer", and all that) doesn't do grey areas i.e. someone can't be almost worthy of the power of Thor. Either they can lift the hammer or they can't. If this is as the case, why was Steve not able to lift Mjolnir completely off the table, since presumably if he can move it *at all* that means that he is in fact worthy?

Comment: Well, some people certainly have speculated that Steve could lift it, but chose not to. That said, it seems likely to me that people can be more or less worthy, and Steve was more worthy than most.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Why isn’t Captain America worthy of Mjolnir?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86932/51379)

Comment: It's not a duplicate post. The question you linked to is asking why Steve's not worthy of the power of Thor. I'm asking why Steve couldn't lift the hammer when the fact that he could move it shows that he's worthy, since Mjolnir doesn't do grey areas.

Comment: Well, it might not be duplicate. I’m not sure, so I did not cast a close vote, but I put it there in case other people are more certain.

Comment: Related: [Does Captain America purposely avoid picking up Thor’s Hammer in Avengers 2?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128941/51379)

Comment: @Arianna Why do you think it doesn't do grey area?

Comment: Because the enchantment specifically says "if he be worthy" which is a very black and white sort of phrase. There's no room for almost in the spell that determines a potential wielder's worthiness.

Comment: @Arianna: “There's no room for almost in the spell that determines a potential wielder's worthiness.” Fictional magic would *never* be that inconsistent!

Comment: Mjolnir seems to be.

Comment: i never read the comics, but i think i saw a wiki post that says through out history in comic, many have lifted the hammer in times of great peril or when they become worthy at that instance. I am sorry i dont have proof or links for it but this would indicate that a person could be totally worthy at one time but may lose the worth later. or a person could be a normal one but prove himself in that particular instance and become worthy of perhaps saving the day for once.

Comment: so basically it depends on worth of a man? so maybe cap started picking up with good intentions but just as the hammer moved, he got proud and greedy? How DO you estimate the worth of a man?