# Could Dr. Strange wield Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir, odin, doctor-strange

According to [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/how-does-mjolnir-determine-worth):

> The person has to be worthy in Odin's eyes, or be able to break the
>   enchantment that Odin placed on the hammer

So what I'm really asking is, is Dr. Strange a powerful enough magician to break Odin's enchantment?

Comment: When you're worthy, why would you need to break the enchantment. Enchantment would simply allow you to wield the Mjolnir.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible for MCU Vision's Mind Stone to override Odin's enchantment?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154412/70236)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. The magic the Asgardians use varies widely in strength depending on the caster. The pronouncements used by Odin are almost unbreakable by the magical abilities of Loki or Carnilla, two of the greatest sorcerers in Asgard. Both of their powers exceed the Sorcerer Supreme's ability. It can be concluded few, if any, have the magical ability to remove Odin's enchantments backed by the Odinforce.

Comment: I'm curious who might be able to override the Odinforce.  For the sake of sanity, limit this to beings' typical powers -- the Infinity Gauntlet is the uber game breaker.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer, Immortus removed one of the enchantments on Mjolnir. Specifically, the enchantment that allowed Mjolnir to be used as a time-travel device.

Comment: So, would it be fair to say, "A simple spell, but quite unbreakable"?

Answer (score 4):

Dr. Strange's power varies from writer to writer. Remember that he single-handedly defeated Galactus a couple times, once even defeating a fully sated Galactus ([Doctor Strange #17](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_5_17)):

[image]

By the way, Strange managed to re-create the universe after that, which Galactus had previously destroyed.

Meanwhile Odin at his mightiest only got to momentarily stun and weaken a hungry Galactus (the Devourer had just eaten one planet before that fight though). Galactus was able to walk away from it, whereas Odin couldn't stand up later ([Mighty Thor #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_1_5)):

[image: Odin headbutts Galactus]

So yeah, the Sorceror Supreme can definitely be more powerful than the All-Father.

---

Also in the past, Stephen was able to summon the Mjolnir, although he did not hold it in his hands ([Strange Tales #123](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_123)):

[image: Get over here!]

And in [Thor #621](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_601) the doctor is even telling Thor that he is going to take the power to recreate Mjolnir for himself (with consent):

[image: Dr. Strange can re-create the Mjolnir]

So yeah, I think Strange can disenchant and reenchant Mjolnir, and lift it, if given a reason to and the time to learn how to do it.

Comment: It's worth noting that when Dr. Strange "summoned" Mjolnir in _Strange Tales Vol 1 #123_, he required a tiny sliver of Mjolnir given to him by Loki in order to make that possible. Before Loki gave him that, he said: _"My spells will not work against so alien an object."_