# What makes Thor "worthy" to lift the Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, norse-gods, mjolnir

How is "worthiness" defined in the context of lifting the Mjolnir? What makes Thor worthy to lift the Mjolnir?

Comment: When facing the Destroyer, he sacrifices himself to rescue his friends, Jane and the townspeople.

Comment: Related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/how-does-mjolnir-determine-worth/4405#4405

Comment: marvel comics or norse mythology?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The related question shows how Mjolnir determines worth, not how Thor is worthy.

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate of the linked question. If anything, it's a duplicate of [Why is Thor worthy to lift Mjolnir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161073/70236)

Comment: @Gallifreyan - That's fair. I've added it as an alternate